# OpenSUSE LEAP 15 installation: mount of /boot/efi from other disk

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, opensuse

I have disks sda and sdb. The disk sda contains OpenSUSE Tumbleweed. I want to install OpenSUSE LEAP 15 on the disk sdb. When I run installer, it shows me a plan of partitioning which looks fine except one line: mount of sda1 to /boot/efi. So, it wants to mount the partition from the sda where is OpenSUSE Tumbleweed while I want to install all to sdb. I suppose it will lead to common boot menu with selection from both OpenSUSEs: from sda and sdb. Or I'm wrong? Is it safe? I tried to change this line with menu but no way: it always finds sda1 and add to plan a mounting of it to /boot/efi.

Another way is to detach sda disk at whole and to install new OpenSUSE which I suppose will lead to selection of boot device from "BIOS" motherboard menu.

So, what is the safe way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot loader always on sda! Kernel may be on a different disk. Going for that will result in a boot menu offering both systems. This will be safe.

Choosing boot device in BIOS will be safe as well. But why shouldn't you use the already existing boot partition?

If you're looking for a perfectly clean solution of migrating from one system to an other, not leaving any trace of the old one, you might want to go for the second way and detach sda for installation of LEAP, but I suggest you go for the first way and remove traces of the system you don't want to use by editing your efi configuration afterwards. (Making a copy of /boot first might be a good idea!)